# 2 Javascript files conflicting in JQM page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to find a way to stop conflicts between two js files on a JQM page. I was wanting to know is there a way to make the js file only load for one data-role=page?

Answer (score 1):

Call a page by its' `ID`, for example.

```
$('[data-role=page]#PageID').on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
 alert('Page with ID ' + $(this)[0].id + ' is here!'
});
```